# How to create angular ag-grids dynamically

Tags: angular, angular8

I am getting data from an `API` call based on the response received from the `API` I have to create `ag-grids`.
let us consider below example.

```
data = ["Usage","Audit"];
```

Since I have two elements in array I have to create  two `ag-grids`, the elements for data can vary it can be one or can be 10.
could anyone please tell me how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through your `data` response in the template.

my-component.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let gridName of data">
  <ag-grid-angular [rowData]="allData[gridName]"
                   [columnDefinitions]="allColumnDefinitions[gridName]">
  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

my-component.component.ts

```
export class MyComponent {
  data = ['One', 'Two'];
  allData = {
    One: [{first: '1'}, {first: '2'}, {first: '3'}],
    Two: [{other: 'A'}, {other: 'B'}, {other: 'C'}]
  }

  allColumnDefinitions: {
    One: [{field: 'first'}, {field: ''}],
    Two: [{field: 'other'}, {field: ''}]
  }
}
```